# Cannot associate event receiver with a particular document library

Tags: list, document-library, event-receivers

I am trying to develop an Event Receiver for a document library titled Temporary. I have modified the Elements.xml document to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Receivers ListUrl="Temporary/Forms">
    <Receiver>
      <Name>CleanUpTemporaryItemAdded</Name>
      <Type>ItemAdded</Type>
      <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
      <Class>MeritSolutions.MAXLife.SP.CleanUpTemporary.CleanUpTemporary</Class>
      <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
    </Receiver>
  </Receivers>
</Elements>
```

When I run the code to debug, it doesn't work - SharePoint Manager 2010 doesn't show that there are any receivers attached to the Temporary document library. I know that the key is in the `ListUrl="Temporary/Forms"` line, but I can't get it to work. I tried with `"Temporary"`, `"/Temporary"`, `"Temporary/Forms"` and `"/Temporary/Forms"`, but nothing helped. My document library is hidden; does that have to do anything with it maybe? My site is the site collection root site, i.e. `http://spserver/sites/site1`. Please help, thanks.

Comment: were you able to fix the problem?

Comment: Just the document library worked for me.  <Receivers Scope="Web" ListUrl="Doc Lib Name">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove 'Forms' from the Url, the ListUrl should only point to the document library.

Next, visit the library in the browser. The url is relative to the web site url. So if your library is at:

`http://webapp/sites/somesite/subsite/Lists/Temporary` then the ListUrl is `Lists/Temporary`.

Comment: Thanks for replying. My Temporary library is at `http://spserver/sites/site1/temporary` There is no "Lists" part as it is not a list; it is a document library. The scope of the feature containing the event receiver is Site, not Web, and I need to keep it that way. Could that be the cause of the issue?

Comment: It doesn't work after all... It is now working on every single document library, regardless of the fact that I specified `<Receivers ListUrl="Lists/Temporary">`!!! Help?

Comment: Get rid of the lists part but keep the `/`

Comment: It is still doesn't work as expected. My event receiver is fired when I am adding new documents both to the `Shared Documents` and the `Temporary` libraries. It appears that the ListURL property is just ignored ...

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this in a Sandboxed solution?

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
<Receivers Scope="Web" ListUrl="Doc Lib Name">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to contribute eventhough it is closed.

Pay attention to this as you should supply the url of the document library and not the display name.

```
E.g.:
Document Library URL: http://myserver.local/deliverynoteinbound
Document Library Title: Delivery Note Inbound
```

For a document library your code should look like this:

```
<Receivers ListUrl="deliverynoteinbound"> //It should be the URL not the Title
```

And for a list it should be like this:

```
<Receivers ListUrl="Lists/somelisturl">
```